# Excel Help - Return Column value based on values on right

Tags: excel

I need some help in Excel. I want to return the value in the first column if that corresponding row has a value greater than 0. The row has 5 columns from Z1 to Z5 (each split into 2 columns - EDI, MPI). If EDI or MPI has a value greater than 0 then that value from column 1 needs to be returned. Please refer to the image url below

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: I dont know how to accomplish this which is why I am asking. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. I don't see the desired outcome on your screenshot.  By showing what you have tried, that is sometimes helpful in trying to figure out what you are trying to do.  You could probably do a formula similar to `if(sum(all_the_columns)>0,column1,"")` To better formulate your problem, I suggest you  read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below formula in `Column L` and drag it down,

```
=IF(SUM(B1:K1)>0,A1,"NULL")
```